# CredSSP not recommended in Production environments

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, remoting, credentials, production-environment

I try deploy Sharepoint WSP projects using PowerShell Remoting.

See https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44880/powershell-remoting-sharepoint-2010-error

Solution is configure CredSSP for Sharepoint.

But Microsoft says:

> Caution: Credential Security Service Provider (CredSSP)
>   authentication, in which the user's credentials are passed to a remote
>   computer to be authenticated, is designed for commands that require
>   authentication on more than one resource, such as accessing a remote
>   network share. This mechanism increases the security risk of the
>   remote operation. If the remote computer is compromised, the
>   credentials that are passed to it can be used to control the network
>   session.

Ref: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347668.aspx

Not recommended in production environments.

Any suggestions for deploy using powershell remoting and sharepoint ?

**UPDATE for Windows XP**

Problem is WinRM 2.0 in Windows XP SP3 doesn't support CredSSP for PowerShell.

Powershell 2.0 - WinRM 2.0 + Windows XP SP3 + CredSSP + Deploy PS Remoting for Sharepoint 2010 NOT IS POSSIBLE

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/is/winserverpowershell/thread/d86d7815-2d3a-43ae-95bd-5f4ebad3f263

Answer (score 2):

They do not recommend it because if the second hop is compromised, there is a risk that all the systems in that remoting chain are compromised. But, if you are doing this in a secure data center type environment, I don't see any risk.

However, if you still need better security, I'd recommend using SSL endpoints.

Comment: any reference or good sample using PS Remoting and "SSL endpoints" (in my case for deploy in Sharepoint servers) ?

Comment: There is nothing specific you need to do for SharePoint as PowerShell remoting is independent of that. Check if this helps: http://rcampi.blogspot.in/2011/10/powershell-remoting-using-ssl.html