# Is it possible to start a process as "nt authority\system" over Powershell remoting?

Tags: powershell, impersonation, psexec, powershell-remoting

I'm automating the testing of the installation, detection, and uninstallation of some Windows applications.  In order to run most of those installers silently, they must be run as `nt authority\system`.  That is easy enough to accomplish on a local machine by invoking `psexec` something like this:

```
psexec -s setup.exe /S
```

I need to be able to automatically roll back the test target computer to known-good states, so I'm using another computer to orchestrate all this.  Ideally I could use PowerShell remoting to start the installer on the target computer.  I haven't yet found a way to achieve that.

### Attempt 1: psexec from a Remote Session

The most obvious thing to do is to connect to the target computer using remoting and invoke [`psexec -s`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).  Here's what that looks like:

```
[target.ad.example.com]: PS C:\Users\un1\Documents> C:\PsTools\PsExec.exe -s whoami
C:\PsTools\PsExec.exe :
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
```

The problem is, the process just hangs at that point.

### Attempt 2: `Start-Process` with `-Verb RunAs`

Using the `RunAs` verb with [`Start-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) may well run a process elevated, but it doesn't seem to run it as `nt authority\system`:

**whoami-to-file.bat**

```
whoami > out.txt
```

**PowerShell Session**

```
[target.ad.example.com]: PS C:\> Start-Process .\whoami-to-file.bat -Verb RunAs -WorkingDirectory
[target.ad.example.com]: PS C:\> Get-Contents out.txt
example\un1
```

The process is *not* started as `nt authority\system`.

### The Question

Is it possible to start a process as `nt authority\system` over PowerShell remoting?  If so, how?

Comment: Did you try `C:\PsTools\PsExec.exe -s -accepteula whoami`?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Nice suggestion. I just tried that and it no longer hangs.  I'm still seeing an error, but now there's hope.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Run procmon on the remote system, execute your command, stop procmon and most likely you'll see something like `whoami not found`in the trace.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers `psexec -s` wasn't even getting that far.  It couldn't launch its helper service which makes sense because remoting+impersonation probably adds up to a double-hop.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33572899/1404637).

Answer (score 2):

*Note: I'm no expert at Windows security and credentials, so I don't understand the exact security implications of this technique.  In my case the only credentials in question are those a temporary test computer, so there isn't much risk.  I doubt this technique is a good idea for production.*

### It's a Double-Hop (I think)

[clymb3r's article](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/03/06/accidental-sabotage-beware-of-credssp/) about CredSSP I *think* explains why `psexec -s` fails over PowerShell remoting.  *I think* that PowerShell remoting counts as one hop and invoking `psexec -s` counts as a second hop.  If that's the case we have a manifestation of [the double-hop authentication problem.](http://powershell.org/wp/kb/the-double-hop-authentication-problem/)

### Use CredSSP

I suppose there are a variety of ways to overcome the double-hop problem.  This being a testing scenario, `CredSSP` seems appropriate ([beware the security risk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278263/credssp-not-recommended-in-production-environments)).  Here's the proof of concept.

First you have to enable CredSSP on both computers:

```
PS C:\> Enable-WSManCredSSP Client -DelegateComputer target.ad.example.com
PS C:\> Invoke-Command { Enable-WSManCredSSP Server} -ComputerName target.ad.example.com
```

Then you can remote to the target using CredSSP:

```
PS C:\> $credential = Get-Credential example\target-admin
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession target.ad.example.com -Credential $credential -Authentication CredSSP
[target.ad.example.com]: PS C:\>
```

And `psexec -s` works:

```
[target.ad.example.com]: PS C:\> psexec -s whoami
C:\PsTools\PsExec.exe :
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
Connecting to local system...Starting PSEXESVC service on local system...Connecting with PsExec service on
target...Starting whoami on target...
whoami exited on target with error code 0.
nt authority\system
```

Comment: No security expert either but I think you are right. Nice find and good to know.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mkellerman/Invoke-CommandAs

Made a function to Invoke-Command as SYSTEM, or provided credential, against local/remote computer. Returns PSObjects, handles network interruptions and resolves any Double-Hop issues.

Try it out let me know if this resolves your issues.